# What does it mean to have a dual channel in an Axi GPIO?

Tags: sdk, gpio, microblaze

I am learning about the Microblaze processors and i don't really understand that while using the gpio functions.

Answer (score 1):

This simply means that you have a second, independent GPIO on the same peripheral.

It's like having 2 different GPIO peripherals, but without the burden of allocating another one (with associated bus attachment logic duplication, etc..)

The Xilinx GPIO peripherals have always been like this, back from the OPB bus ones, to the PLB bus, and then, now, with the newest AXI bus peripherals.

You would have answered yourself by reading the peripheral [documentation](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/axi_gpio/v2_0/pg144-axi-gpio.pdf). (Hint: on Chapter "Register Space", page 10, you see a second set of registers, named "GPIO2_*", which are available only when "dual channel" is enabled)